# High INACTIVE memory

Tags: linux, rhel6, oracle-11g

i usring Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.5 and Oracle Database 11g when i execute "top" show this to me

```
top - 14:08:02 up 5 days, 18:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 340 total,   1 running, 331 sleeping,   8 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  132038392k total, 100871400k used, 31166992k free,    16912k buffers
Swap: 32767996k total,        0k used, 32767996k free, 99462140k cached
```

i dedicate 70GB memory to my Database so when i start my database show following error

```
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
```

then i execute "vmstat -s" show following output

```
132038392  total memory
100928456  used memory
   278536  active memory
 99495304  inactive memory
```

i realize 96GB of my used memory is INACTIVE memory then i used following command to free up my INACTIVE memory

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

nothing happened and still i cant start my database unless i reboot my OS
How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: I think this is talking about temp shared memory filesystem (shmfs/tmpfs). Can you check your df and see what you have for `tmpfs`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for answering to me. i checked that and this is exact 95GB used of tmpfs. so how can i release that. still i can't start my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to solve this  problem with the below string of commands:

first of all
Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches  Once dropped, their
memory becomes free.

```
To free pagecache:

echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

if this problem wasnot resolve then
you should to do it:

```
Now change the value by modifying /etc/sysctl.conf 
kernel.shmmax 
kernel.shmall 
then force the system to activate this setting file without a reboot.
$ sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

[1] Below command to mount is manually

mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=70g /dev/shm

[2] Then try

SQL> startup nomount
If all works add below line to fstab to make it persistent.

"tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   size=72g        0 0"

I hope server having enough resources for db and other process.